# Android Sensors not giving any values but zeroes

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm using sensors to determine phone's orientation (relative to the earth's frame of reference, as in actual x, y and z values) and the sensors don't output anything but zeroes. However, when I log sensor's output, they output zeroes at a constant rate, like 10 times per second and each of those is a zero as well.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(mLayout);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() ==(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)) {
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mAccelerometerReading,
                0, mAccelerometerReading.length);
    }
    else if (event.sensor.getType() == (Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)) {
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mMagnetometerReading,
                0, mMagnetometerReading.length);
    }
    refreshText();
}

public void updateOrientationAngles() {
    // Update rotation matrix, which is needed to update orientation angles.
    mSensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null,
            mAccelerometerReading, mMagnetometerReading);

    // "mRotationMatrix" now has up-to-date information.

    mSensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mOrientationAngles);

    // "mOrientationAngles" now has up-to-date information.
}

public void refreshText () {
    updateOrientationAngles();
    anglesText = "X: " + mOrientationAngles[0] + "\nY: " + mOrientationAngles[1] + "\nZ: " + mOrientationAngles[2];
    angles.setText(anglesText);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "angles:  " + anglesText);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

    refreshText();
}
```

Due to the logs showing sensors actually outputting something, I'd say listeners are registered correctly, but something else is wrong. However, it seems that sensors are outputting even if the phone is perfectly still. Ty for any help.

Comment: what you want to achieve? want to get current orientation?

Comment: Yes. In refreshText method I'm trying to get values of orientation and that text would that be showed on screen.

Comment: Did you initialize mRotationMatrix?